# Storing multi-dimensional attributes (columns) in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

What is the best way of storing items with several entries (fixed length) in a `pandas` `DataFrame` column? I’m thinking of something like a 3D position vector. For example, if my `DataFrame` is storing data about a bunch of physical objects, it could look like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'type': [1, 2, 1, 1, 3],
    'mass': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5],
    'pos': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]],
    'vel': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
})
#    mass           pos  type           vel
# 0   1.1     [1, 2, 3]     1     [1, 2, 3]
# 1   2.2     [4, 5, 6]     2     [4, 5, 6]
# 2   3.3     [7, 8, 9]     1     [7, 8, 9]
# 3   4.4  [10, 11, 12]     1  [10, 11, 12]
# 4   5.5  [13, 14, 15]     3  [13, 14, 15]
```

Here, the columns `'pos'` and `'vel'` are the positions and velocities of the objects in 3D space.

I have thought of several options, none of which seem ideal or even work:

1. Storing Python lists as values in the column. This is basically what I showed in the example above. Unfortunately, this is very inefficient.
2. Splitting the column into several different ones:

   ```
   df = pandas.DataFrame({
       'type': [1, 2, 1, 1, 3],
       'mass': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5],
       'x': [1, 4, 7, 10, 13],
       'y': [2, 5, 8, 11, 14],
       'z': [3, 6, 8, 12, 15],
       'vx': [1, 4, 7, 10, 13],
       'vy': [2, 5, 8, 11, 14],
       'vz': [3, 6, 8, 12, 15]
   })
   #    mass  type  vx  vy  vz   x   y   z
   # 0   1.1     1   1   2   3   1   2   3
   # 1   2.2     2   4   5   6   4   5   6
   # 2   3.3     1   7   8   8   7   8   8
   # 3   4.4     1  10  11  12  10  11  12
   # 4   5.5     3  13  14  15  13  14  15
   ```

   This seems like it would become cumbersome for larger attributes. But at least it’s efficient?
3. I’ve also tried assigning a multi-dimensional `numpy` array to the column, but unfortunately, `pandas` refuses:

   ```
   pos = numpy.array([[11, 12, 13],
                      [22, 23, 24],
                      [33, 34, 35],
                      [44, 45, 46],
                      [55, 56, 57]])
   df.loc[:, 'pos'] = pos
   # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
   # <ipython-input-228-2ee95dd5aa19> in <module>()
   # ----> 1 df.loc[:, 'pos'] = pos
   # 
   # /opt/anaconda-3/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   #     177             key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
   #     178         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
   # --> 179         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
   #     180 
   #     181     def _has_valid_type(self, k, axis):
   # 
   # /opt/anaconda-3/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
   #     561                     value = np.array(value, dtype=object)
   #     562                     if len(labels) != value.shape[1]:
   # --> 563                         raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
   #     564                                          'when setting with an ndarray')
   #     565 
   # 
   # ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
   ```

Comment: using numpy arrays you can store them, as of now I can say that

Comment: If want use vectorized operations only possible solution is `2. Splitting the column into several different ones` or use `numpy 2d arrays`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like this

```
d = pd.concat([
    df[['mass', 'type']],
    pd.DataFrame(df.pos.tolist(), df.index, ['x', 'y', 'z']),
    pd.DataFrame(df.vel.tolist(), df.index, ['x', 'y', 'z'])
], axis=1, keys=['Scalar', 'Position', 'Velocity'])

d

  Scalar      Position         Velocity        
    mass type        x   y   z        x   y   z
0    1.1    1        1   2   3        1   2   3
1    2.2    2        4   5   6        4   5   6
2    3.3    1        7   8   9        7   8   9
3    4.4    1       10  11  12       10  11  12
4    5.5    3       13  14  15       13  14  15
```

---

You can easily access from top level

```
d.Velocity

    x   y   z
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
4  13  14  15
```

Or do math

```
(d.Velocity + d.Position).div(d.Scalar.mass, axis=0)

          x         y         z
0  1.818182  3.636364  5.454545
1  3.636364  4.545455  5.454545
2  4.242424  4.848485  5.454545
3  4.545455  5.000000  5.454545
4  4.727273  5.090909  5.454545
```

And you still can get easy access to an appropriate Numpy array

```
d.Position.values

array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Option #2: store coordinates in integer series across multiple columns. It's the only option that makes sense with Pandas.

The main property you should consider is the `dtype` of your resultant series. With Option #1, you will have `object` series, which is nothing more than a sequence of pointers. This can be achieved equally well with `list` and you lose all ability to perform vectorised calculations.

With Option #3, Pandas gets confused trying to assign a sequence of NumPy arrays to a single series. The error in itself demonstrates Pandas is not designed to be used in this way.